# How to avoid encoding of < and > in html page source?

Tags: html

I have a scenario where I am generating xml on html page. It looks like

```
<esi:vars>
    <esi:assign name="searchresultstitle">'''SearchResults_srch_title'''</esi:assign>
```

But when I view the source of this page by doing 'view page source' I see something like

<esi:comment text="Translation variables"/>

```
&lt;esi:vars&gt;
    &lt;esi:assign name=&#034;searchresultstitle&#034;&gt;&#039;&#039;&#039;SearchResults_srch_title&#039;&#039;&#039;&lt;/esi:assign&gt;
```

But I need to show it as it is on html page.
Is there any solution for this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use `<pre>` tags for pre-formatted display

```
<pre>
<esi:assign name="searchresultstitle">'''SearchResults_srch_title'''</esi:assign>
</pre>
```

**[pre](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre)**

> The HTML Preformatted Text (`<pre>`) represents preformatted text. Text within this element is typically displayed in a non-proportional font exactly as it is laid out in the file. Whitespaces inside this element are displayed as typed

Comment: Hi Hanky. Thanks for such a quick reply. But I  am writing this inside <pre> tag. On html page it is fine. I am having problem on page source where < and > of esi tag gets encoded into &lt anf &gt respectively.

Comment: @Rajeev Of course it looks like that; the entities **must** be escaped to avoid being interpreted as HTML. How on earth could it be valid to have unescaped XML inside XML? The answer is, it's not.

Comment: And on top of that, what purpose does it serve for you to have it display as it is in the source as well? Browsers need to do something in order to escape them properly and display fine.

Comment: Thanks Christian.
You mean to say that < and > could be shown on only one place. Either on html page or in page Source ?
Because if I do not escape the xml then it looks like 

'''SearchResults_srch_title'''

on html page and 

<esi:vars>
        <esi:assign name="searchresultstitle">'''SearchResults_srch_title'''</esi:assign>

on page source.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky. My Client want me to do that. I guess it is needed in some kind of searching.